# How does Superman forge a sword?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

In the JLU episode *Hereafter*, Superman is stranded in a future where the sun is burnt out (to a red sun?) and he no longer had his powers. He still manages to forge a very nice sword from a pipe and some road flares. This isn't some lump of metal with an edge. It *gleams*.

[image: The image shows Superman's head and shoulders and the length of the sword blade he holds in front of himself. Superman has a full, dark beard and longish hair, and his cape appears purple. The blade has perfectly straight sides and the light glints off it.]

Is this meant to imply that he has superblacksmithing powers (unrelated to his yellow sun powers), or is such a feat manageable by most people? Does he even have experience with forging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have some experience blacksmithing - you couldn't make a blade from a pipe and road flares, but the problem is the flares, not the pipe. You'd need a forge, which isn't terribly difficult to create (a lot of folks make these out of barbecues), some decent hammers, and some decent stock.

A lot of folks use springs, leaf or coil, as starting stock. But I guess to answer your question directly - given enough time to figure it out, and a few resources, *you* could do it.

Growing up on a farm might have taught him some basic metalworking, but even on the fifties he'd be working with welding tools primarily.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to hear from some one with experience. I've seen people make knives out of horse shoes and rail road spikes, so it wasn't the pipe that struck me as odd, but the fact he didn't have a forge, anvil or hammer to hand.

Comment: Dunno what resources were available, but my first thought about the Flares... With his heat vision, Superman would likely have never had much experience making fire.. Those would make handy matches to get things started, even with tough ignition targets.

Comment: Yeah...the only thing is, you're going to be making hundreds, maybe thousands of fires to get to the point where you can make a decent sword. There ARE primitive ways to sustain fire (or at least, heat which can be re-kindled), so it doesn't enter into it too much...ultimately, under ANY interpretation, any human could do this. I mean, obviously, at some point in the distant past, someone did, so...

Comment: Presumably this is a steel tube like some railings are made of, rather than a literal water pipe, since those are made of lead or copper, neither of which would be much good for swords.